# CasperJS how to check verbose value (True or False) , Loglevel in casper js code

Tags: logging, casperjs

1. I have a scenario like I need to check what is the current log level for the casperJS . Can I ?
2. Can i introduce any custom log level in casperJS. 
   I have gone through the documentation but I could not find any information.

   Thanks,

   Arjun N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your current log level

```
casper.echo(casper.options.logLevel)
```

You can see what other attributes are available in the casper object using

```
casper.echo(Object.keys(casper))
```

As for adding your own log level. Have a look at 
[the source code.](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/modules/casper.js) add/edit the casper object appropriately

Comment: your guidance was really help full .
https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/3da55a100da3885d246a4fda59f318b1e365fc53/samples/customlogging.js

Comment: For custom logging example you can go through this link : https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/3da55a100da3885d246a4fda59f318b1e365fc53/samples/customlogging.js